# Deactivate (not hide) scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, scrollbar

Is there an easy way in GWT/JavaScript to deactivate a scrollbar? It should still be visible but grayed out. It should only rely on GWT, pure JavaScript and/or CSS. The only things I found was how to hide the scrollbar but that's not what I need.

So far I found a feasible solution which sets the scrollbar height to 0 while I want it to be deactivate and set the height back to the normal value once I resume navigation.

Comment: is css solution ok?

Comment: Yes, that would be OK as well. I will mention this

Comment: `body{position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%;}` - here you go

Comment: You don't need jQuery, e.g. `document.querySelector('selector').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false; })`

Comment: If you want to have an answer to relate to, and upvote, I can post one at the dupe link using the above javascript version, though I find that not necessary as it is easy to search for a jQuery-to-javascript event handler replacement.

Comment: @LGSon As I understand your solution prevents the events after the scrollbar has been moved but it can be moved?

Comment: Since you said you couldn't use jQuery, what I wanted to show was how one use plain javascript instead, to attach a handler. The solution itself isn't mine, I just linked to it, but in short, when the event fires, the called methods prevent an element to e.g. scroll.

Comment: I understand that. But this still allows the scrollbar to be moved - with no effect - but that is in my opinion confusing behaviour and is not be a reasonable solution.